# Use cases of 'signum' for ordered numeric types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, sign, absolute-value

The `signum` function is the implementation of the usual [mathematical definition of sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), which conditionally returns a value in {-1,0,1}. It is a theoretical definition, and as such, it doesn't take into account computational costs of operations, or data type of values, so that multiplying by (-1) is a zero cost theoretical way of changing sign. Because of that, it is not the most useful treatment of sign for programming.

The case `signum a == 0` is not really useful, as you can always test directly `a == 0`, without the extra cost of computing `signum a`. As for the other two values, I think that they are used in just 3 general ways:

- either you test if a value is positive or negative to launch different code conditionally, as in:

  ```
  f x y | signum x == -1  = h x y
        | otherwise       = g x y
  ```
- or you multiply something by `1` or `-1` before operate with it, as in:

  ```
  f x y = g x (y * b) where 
        b = signum x
  ```
- or you add `1` or `-1` to something before operate with it, as in:

  ```
  f x y = g x (y + b) where 
        b = signum x
  ```

In all cases, it would be better a `Bool` value for sign. So, we just need functions to decompose a `Num` into absolute value and boolean sign, and an inverse function, which changes the sign of a value depending of a boolean condition (which represents a sign). This function is the equivalent of multiplying `1` or `-1` by a number, so we define it as an operator similar to `(*)`. :

```
sgn  a      = a >= 0
(*.) a True = a
(*.) a _    = -a
abs  a      = a *. sgn a
signum1 a   = 1 *. sgn a
```

I added a dichotomous variant of `signum` which can only return ´{-1,1}´. Notice that preceding it with `signum 0 = 0` we would get the usual `signum` function, but that third case is what I think that is not generally useful.

We can code similarly an adding operator, because it is a very frequent case to add `1` or `-1` depending on the sign of something (you can see that these operators just treat `True` as `1` and `False` as `-1`):

```
(+.) a b    = a + 1 *. b
(-.) a b    = a - 1 *. b
```

We could even enclose the declarations in a class called `Signed`, for easier use, including proper signatures and fixity.

This way, the above general examples would simplify, not just in code, but also in execution time and space, because we avoid multiplication (using `(*.)` instead), we avoid extra comparison once we have a `Bool`, we can get the sign from one type of data and use it for another type without needing type conversion, and we use the short type `Bool` instead of a potentially long type of class `Num`. But we get more flexibility, while allowing some optimization of code and data types.

My question, then, is if there are cases different than the three general use cases exposed here, that is, cases not easily covered by this approach, cases for which the current `signum` function is advantageous against a Bool sign approach. More precisely, can I avoid completely the use of the current `signum` function without losing efficiency or code clarity?

---

**Edit**: I modified the first paragraph to a more "neutral" fashion, following Reid Barton comment.

---

**Progress update:** the code for this approach was greatly improved for simplicity and clarity, with the great help of the current answers and comments.

Comment: Looks to me that zero is just a different case. You cannot say the *sign* of zero is "+". It is both "+" and "-" at the same time since `-0 == +0`. (No i did not dv).

Comment: I think this question could be posed in a more "neutral" fashion.

Comment: The Haskell 2010 report only requires that `abs x * signum x == x`; it says nothing about the size of the codomain of `signum`.

Comment: Let's suppose this is just a "definition made by academic mathematicians, who don't worry about computational costs of operations", then why does Java do the same thing? For types like int, keeping them on the stack (even if you multiply it) is often more efficient than having a cache-miss from the indirection of extra boxed types.

Comment: @Reid, I edited the post following your suggestion.

Comment: The Bool option means you only have 2 cases when 3 might be needed ... Also your main concern seems  to be about efficiency vs usefulness. That looks like premature optimisation for me especially as numeric operation are fairly quick on today's computer.

Comment: The sign in signed types is just one bit, that is the main motivation to consider it `Bool`. I was working with a data list where I wanted to save the sign of polynomial terms paired with the exponent of the term, for large number of terms. I was not comfortable saving `[(Integer, Integer)]` (terms should be `Integer`) when I just need `[(Int, Bool)]`. On the other side, testing always 3 cases when you need 2 cases more often than not, is not the optimal way of working. For the requirement  of `x == abs x * signum x`, it is enough a 2 valued `signum` function, it is simpler and faster.

Comment: Well, if you don't need 3 values but only 2, you can just use `(>=0)` instead and you get your Bool. I'm not sure we need to modify signum for that. If you really have a special need because of performance issue, then rolling your own function is acceptable.

Comment: That is what I was always, always, doing, but not just for performance. So I started to think on a more structured way of treating sign. Finally, with all the help here, I wrote [this class](http://lpaste.net/352118) for my own use, that I share for the interested. It makes my project easier, as some patterns of use are repeated in my work. I choosed Reid example as the best for helping to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used a function like this to navigate a cursor to a target offset in a square grid by a series of moves to (orthogonally and diagonally) adjacent cells.

```
move :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
move (0, 0) = []
move (x, y) = (dx, dy) : move (x - dx, y - dy)
  where dx = signum x
        dy = signum y
```

Comment: Good example. But you are computing `signum` on each recursion, which is redundant as the sign is the same while it is not zero. For large inputs you should better try to precompute the sign out of the recursion, as well as `abs x` and `abs y`, and treat apart the cases of one of the coordinates being zero. And then, the apparent advantage of `signum` for this case is in doubt (I think is not).

Comment: @enrique If you profile the code and see that results in a large bottleneck for input that you are running it on, you can avoid that recomputation [by using the common Haskell idiom of a "`go`" function](http://lpaste.net/351956). I'm not sure why it would be necessary to compute the absolute values here, though.

Comment: @David, your code is incomplete, as it needs the separate cases of one coordinate becoming zero when the other one is not zero. But you are right, we don't need `abs` if we use `signum`. This example is good.

Comment: [Here](http://lpaste.net/352015) is the optimized version of this example using `signum`, based on the incorrect [@David solution](http://lpaste.net/351956), and the one using my approach. You can see that first solution doesn't really use the return value `0` from `signum`, as we both need explicit code lines for the cases of one only coordinate becoming zero.

Answer (score 9):

You are assuming that "positive" and "negative" are the only two possible signs. But for e.g. `Complex Double`, the `signum` operation returns a complex number with the same "direction" but magnitude 1:

```
Data.Complex> signum (3 :+ 4)
0.6 :+ 0.8
```

Comment: True, but that raises the question why this is called “signum”. Arguably this operation should be called `normalise` or something similar, and it should not map 0 to 0 (as that does not have unit modulus).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'd prefer the shorter `norm`. That aside, the `sgn` function is a [thing in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), and its usual generalization in complex numbers assigns `sgn(0) = 0`.

Comment: @Alec `norm` would be even more misleading – a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) is basically the generalisation of `abs` to metric vector spaces`.

Comment: It seems that my approach only works for "signed" types ;-). In fact, it can be seen on the signatures that it is only for ordered types. But ok, what I am dealing with is not applicable to generalized signum function (that is why I used another name, `sgn`, for a boolean sign). Thank you, your comments and answer helped me.

Answer (score 4):

To address the question of time complexity:

Branches are not free and if you have to (in concept) multiply values by the result of signum of the same value in several different spots, it would likely be more efficient to have `let s = signum x in ...` or have that binding in a `where`-clause. You no longer have to go through a branch every time. Also keep in mind that [in some cases, code can slow down due to branching behavior that goes against what the branch predictor expects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array).

For example, say you have code like this:

```
f x y z = (s * y) / (1 + (s * z))
  where
    s = signum x
```

Analysis of efficiency is often not as clear cut as you might expect and can be *highly* dependent on very specific aspects of a particular program, as can be seen in the question I linked above, hence the oft quoted advice of "profile before optimizing". In the question I linked  to, the version of the code which executes more instructions actually runs *faster* than the version that executes *fewer* instructions (I can verify these results on my machine, even if I include the extra instructions of sorting in the profiling)!

Comment: What about the type of `x` being different than the types of `y` and `z` in your example?. In my proposed approach it is not a problem, as all of them have to be instances of `Num` (and type of `x` an instance of `Ord`). I mean, efficiency is not the only, not the main, issue, it is consistency.

Comment: @enrique I'm not sure I see what you mean. Ultimately, things must be the same type if you are going to use `*`, `/` and `+` on them, as in an example like this. You will need conversion functions in either approach if they are different types. The presence or absence of `signum` doesn't change that. And you can also be consistent by using `signum` everywhere...

Comment: I would argue that `signum` is also conceptually simpler, because it only requires one, pretty simple, function. Only one function name to remember, it's clear which results correspond to positive and negative (it would be easier to forget what `True` means) and zero and you can use it directly with other mathematical operations like the `+` without requiring some sort of `if`, guard or `case`. And incidentally zero is neither negative nor positive so which `Bool` value should that be? And how should you remember that?

Comment: Think of `setSgn s y` as an overloaded `(*) s y`, where `s` is `Bool` and `y` can be any type of class `Num`. So, you don't need conversion. I would call that function `(*)` if ad-hoc polymorphism would be possible in Haskell. The conceptual simplicity for me is that `signum` and `abs` should be really two faces of the same operation (which is not, see sources), the descomposition of any number into both (also for zero), in a similar fashion as `quotRem`, so that you shouldn't need to call two functions if you need `signum` and `abs`, which is a usual case.

Comment: There should be also a composition operation, inverse of that decomposition (which is `(*)`, ok, despite not being polymorphic). Often, `signum` is used as a conditional, and this is the main motivation for thinking that it would be convenient to be a Bool value, adding the fact that the information of sign is enclosed in just one bit for signed types. Besides, `{*,+1,-1}` is a cyclic group, while `{*,+1,0,-1}` is not. So, finally, the main thing which doesn't fit is the value zero, as correctly points leftaround in a comment to Daniel answer.

Comment: @enrique That's not the conversion I mean. If you want something like `a + (s * b)`, the types will need to be the same for `+`. Usually, there are more arithmetic operations involved when `signum` is used than just multiplying by the result. Overall, I can find real world use cases for `signum` from implementing mathematical concepts (this is what the question title is asking). I would also pose a counter-question: what is a use case of your method that is an improvement over something that uses `signum` (not just an example of how it works, something that implements a "real world" thing)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134635/discussion-between-david-young-and-enrique).